# Zend_Tool multiple .zfproject.xml

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to create custom folder to put multiple applications and get Zend_Tool to working:

```
applications 
|- frontend
   |- configs
   |- controllers
   |- models
   |- tests
   |- views
   |- .zfproject.xml
   |- Bootstrap.php
|- backend
   |- configs
   |- controllers
   |- models
   |- tests
   |- views
   |- .zfproject.xml
   |- Bootstrap.php
system
public
docs
```

How to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `create module` command

```
zf create module frontend
zf create module backend
```

After it your folder structurer will be following.

```
applications
     configs  
     controllers  
     models  
     modules  
       |- frontend
         |- configs
         |- controllers
         |- models
         |- tests
         | - views             
         |- Bootstrap.php
       |- backend
         |- configs
         |- controllers
         |- models
         |- tests
         |- views            
         |- Bootstrap.php
     views    
system
public
docs
```

I think it is good structure for project. Also you can use default module as a front end or backend.